# bash total and average ... and more

Tags: bash, loops, variables, if-statement

I'm trying to get this

```
Enter Incidents
Mon 14 
Tue 5
Wed 12

Incidents

Mon 14
Tue 5
Wed 12

Total 38

Average 7.6
------------------------

Mon incidents is the highest 11
Tue incidents is the lowest 2
------------------------

Enter a Day that you'd like to see how many incidents occurred? Wed 
12 Incidents
------------------------
```

So far I did the total and average, Max and min.

The problem is how to output "**Mon** is the highest 11. I'm able to find the min and max but can't print out the day matches the value of max and min....

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " ----Enter Incidents-----"



echo -n "Mon= " 
read days[0]


echo -n "Tue= "
read days[1]


echo -n "Wed= " 
read days[2]






echo " ------Incidents--------"


total=`expr ${days[0]} + ${days[1]} + ${days[2]}`


echo "Toatal is= " $total 


ave=`expr $total \/ 3`


echo "Average= " $ave



max=${days[0]} 

min=${days[0]} 



for i in "${days[@]}"

do

if [[ "$i" -gt "$max" ]]; then 

    max="$i" 
fi 


if [[ "$i" -lt "$min" ]]; then

    min="$i" 

fi 

done 


echo "Max is:" $max

echo "Min is:" $min 


this is killing me lol 
Mon incidents is the highest 11
Tue incidents is the lowest 2
------------------------

Enter a Day that you'd like to see how many incidents occurred? Wed 
12 Incidents
-------------------------------
```

Comment: Properly format the code in your question. Also, aren't you suppose to read the days as well? Currently you're just reading the events.

Comment: How or why did 3 get subtracted from the incident counts for Monday and Tuesday when reporting the min/max?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post in the site. plus I'm very new to bash.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
echo -n "Mon= " read days[0]
```

by

```
read -p "Mon= " days[0]
```

also replace

```
expr something
```

by

```
$(( somthing )) # space matters
```

and please format you code so it is readable in the question.

Comment: I did what you suggested and no different!